Covariance matrix in terms of $X^TX$
If I have a matrix $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, then I can write the covariance as
$$\text{Cov}(X) = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_X)(X-\mu_X)^T]$$
Now, assuming the data is centered, this becomes $\text{Cov}(X) = \mathbb{E}[XX^T]$. I've seen posts saying that the covariance is $XX^T$, whilst others mention $X^TX$ as being the covariance. I don't quite follow how either are derived here.

ultimately it just comes down to the convention of whether you write the matrix such that each row is a datpoint and each column is a feature or vice versa

Related (maybe dups) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193505/express-correlation-matrix-of-x-in-terms-of-xtx-in-the-ols-context, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285353/why-can-the-covariance-matrix-be-computed-as-fracx-xtn-1,

It comes down to what you mean by "the covariance!"  How exactly does your $X$ represent data: with observations in rows or with observations in columns?

In this notation with an expectation $$\text{Cov}(X) = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_X)(X-\mu_X)^T]$$ and $$\text{Cov}(X) = \mathbb{E}[XX^T]$$ is seems like $X$ is a vector instead of a matrix.

$\mathbf{X}$ is a row vector
Say $\mathbf{X}$ is a row vector $$ \mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}X_1 & X_2&\cdots & X_p \end{bmatrix}$$ then
$$\mathbf{X}^T\cdot \mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \\  \vdots \\ X_p \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} X_1 & X_2 & \cdots & X_p \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 X_1 X_1& X_1 X_2 & \cdots &  X_1 X_p \\
X_2 X_1& X_2 X_2 & \cdots &  X_2 X_p \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
X_p X_1& X_p X_2 & \cdots &  X_p X_p \\    \end{bmatrix} $$
So the cross product produces a matrix where the $i$-th row and $j$-th column are the product of the $i$-th and $j$-th element of the vector $\mathbf{X}$.
$\mathbf{X}$ is a column vector
Say $\mathbf{X}$ is a column vector $$\mathbf{ X} = \begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ X_2 \\ \vdots \\ X_p \end{bmatrix}$$ then
$$\mathbf{X}\cdot \mathbf{X}^T = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \\  \vdots \\ X_p \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} X_1 & X_2 & \cdots & X_p \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 X_1 X_1& X_1 X_2 & \cdots &  X_1 X_p \\
X_2 X_1& X_2 X_2 & \cdots &  X_2 X_p \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
X_p X_1& X_p X_2 & \cdots &  X_p X_p \\    \end{bmatrix} $$
So the cross product produces a matrix where the $i$-th row and $j$-th column are the product of the $i$-th and $j$-th element of the vector $\mathbf{X}$.
$\mathbf{X}$ is a matrix
You mention $\mathbf{X}$ to be a matrix. This can be the case if you have $n$ multiple measurements. For example say you have $n$ row vectors like the first section above and place them in a matrix where each row is such vector (to keep the post short, I skip the case when you have several column vectors)
$$ \mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
X_{11} & X_{12}& \dots & X_{1p} \\
X_{21}&X_{22}& \dots & X_{2p} \\
\vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
X_{n1}&X_{n2}&\dots & X_{np} \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then you could contemplate a product like
$$\boldsymbol{\Sigma} = \mathbf{X}^T\cdot \mathbf{X} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{11} & X_{21}& \cdots & \cdots & X_{n1} \\
X_{12} & X_{22}& \cdots & \cdots & X_{n2} \\
\vdots& \vdots & \cdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
X_{1p} & X_{2p}& \cdots & \cdots & X_{np} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{11} & X_{12}& \dots & X_{1p} \\
X_{21}&X_{22}& \dots & X_{2p} \\
\vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
X_{n1}&X_{n2}&\dots & X_{np} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the entries of that matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ are
$$\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} {X}_{ki} {X}_{kj}  $$
So the cross product produces a matrix where the $i$-th row and $j$-th column are a sum of the products of pairs of elements from the $i$-th and $j$-th columns of the matrix $\mathbf{X}$.

Note: if this crossproduct of the matrix $\mathbf{X}$ is used to estimate the expectation of the covariance matrix for the vectors in that matrix, then an additional division by $n$ is to be added, because you want the average of the $n$ terms ${X}_{ik} {X}_{jk}$ and not the sum (or a division by $n-1$, which is the Bessel correction for the bias in such estimate).

Your notation is not precise.
If you write $Cov(X)$ then $X$ is a random vector (col or row?) of dimension $n$, so it really is $X_i(\omega)$.
I normally prefer column vectors so $Cov(X) = \mathbb{E}[XX^T]$ which is a matrix.
If you write $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, then this is your data ($n$ assets, $p$ observations).
Since there are $n$ assets, the covariance matrix is $n \times n$ and the only way to make this happen is $X X^T$.
If you transpose $X$, the formulas will be transposed too. Both conventions are valid.
Whatever do, make sure you get a $n \times n$ matrix.
EDIT:
If one wanted to be more precise, one could say that the $\mathbb{X_i}$ are $n$ random variables ($\mathbb{X}$ as a column vector) and that $x_{ij}$ are $p$ realisations ($i \in 1 \dots n, j \in 1 \dots p$), together called $X$.
Then: $Cov(\mathbb{X}) = \mathbb{E} \left [ \mathbb{X} \mathbb{X}^T \right ] \sim \frac{X X^T}{p}$

Welcome to CV, Andrea.  Although what you're saying will be apparent to knowledgeable readers, others might find the sudden, unannounced change of perspective from random variables to data to be confusing.  This could benefit from more explanation.

Indeed. This sudden change originates fro the original question, between the 1st and the 2nd line. I am simply stating it.

That's an unhelpful interpretation.  The reference to "data" in the question suggests the first part of your answer is not even relevant.  The crux of the matter, IMHO, is to point out the distinction between formulas for data and formulas for random variables and then go on from there.

"then this is your data ($n$ assets, $p$ observations)." Or is it $n$ observations and $p$ parameters?

@Sextus Good point.  The description of $n$ assets (variables) and $p$ observations given in this post is consistent with "I ... prefer row vectors."  However, that description is not consistent with the subsequent covariance formula, because when $X$ is a row vector, $XX^\prime$ is a scalar.

Totally right! I visualize a column, but I wrote a row. Fixed.
